# How is "yowee" supposed to be written in japanese? (e.g. "anta wa yoweenda yo!", meaning "you're weak!")

Tags: slang, orthography, spoken-language

When people are speaking crassly, things like じゃない will often be pronounced じゃねえ, with maybe a few variations (e.g. じゃねー, or using katakana, etc.). My question is, how does one usually do this for "弱{よわ}い"? Do they use うぇ? or ゑ? Or 弱え? Or what? Sorry if this question is super simple.

How is it usually written when one contracts "知った事じゃない" to "shitta kotchanee!"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traditionally, the Japanese language did not have the sound of うぇ. That's why the verb わらう conjugates like わらえ rather than わらうぇ, わらいます rather than わらうぃます and so on.

よわい also contracts to よえー rather than ようぇー. Likewise, つよい becomes つえー rather than ついぇー.

"Shitta kotchanee" is しったこっちゃねえ or しったこっちゃねー.

Japanese people recognize sounds like うぇ, うぃ and いぇ today, but they are almost exclusively used for loanwords.

Comment: Technically, there were [wi] (ゐ, ヰ) and [we] (ゑ, ヱ), and by 13th century they merged with [i] (い, イ) and [je] (え, エ) in pronunciation, although old kana characters may have remained in spelling. There were also [kwi], [gwi], [kwe], [gwe] sequences, which merged with [ki], [gi], [ke], [ge].